# Cannot select image and upload?

Tags: java, android, database, algorithm, firebase

I'm teaching myself about FireBase storage, and I decided to make a simple app that lets the user pick an image, and it uploads it to Firebase. **However, as soon as I select the image to upload, my app crashes and saying that my URI is null, even though I'm getting it from the image I select**

[Full stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a5abcaee16d47710723d9007ff50f308)

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                //Get image
                 path = extras.getParcelable("data");
            }
            StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            storageRef.putFile(path)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            Log.e("myTag", "done, " +downloadUrl);
                            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);     
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                          Log.e("myTag", exception.toString());
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

I've been trying to solve this error for over five hours, and am still confused despite going through the docs a billion times. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The selected `Uri` is returned as [the data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData()) of the `Intent`, not as an extra.  Try this change:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        path = data.getData(); // assumes path is declared as a Uri
        StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images");
        storageRef.putFile(path)...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried that, and now my exception changed to `Cannot upload to getRoot. You should upload to a storage location such as .getReference('image.png').putFile...`

Comment: I also tried adjusting the rules in firebase to allow read and right as always true, but I'm still getting this error. What should I do?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: I updated my answer.  Create your ref to a subfolder of root, e.g. "images": `StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images")`